How to change password on the Odin Project's Xubuntu?
I have created a Xubuntu account to start the Odin Project and either I mistyped the password or something went wrong but it keeps saying Password incorrect. Please try again. Not sure how to change my password. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If Xubuntu is similar enough to Ubuntu, use the method described in How to Reset Forgotten Ubuntu Password in 2 Minutes. Let me know if it worked for you.
